# Using HierachyID to store time series data

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a SQL Server database that holds a large number of time series records -currently about 500 million.  Each record has a datetime and a double data value which form the time series, and two other datetimes values.  I'm looking at ways to improve the performance of queries without going down the data warehouse route.

Instead of storing the data and time as a DateTime I was looking at the new HierachyID in SQL Server 2008 and wondering if it would be possible to use this to store the date and time.  I would imagine that the hierachy would be year, month, day, hour, minute.

Would this provide any performance gains and how would the indexing work?

Comment: Thinking about this some more, the maintenance of a HierachyID column would be a real pain.  It would need triggers to update the parent record in the hierachy which would fire recursively.
A simple data warehousing solution might be better.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it.  Plus it would make programming against it much more complex.  Is your clustered index on the datetime column?  What kind of queries have bad performance?  Also since you seem to not need sub-minute precision, you can reduce the size of your index pages by 4bytes per row if you move to SMALLDATETIME.  Lower I/O = better performance.

Comment: Thanks.  I have a clusted index on the main datetime column which is giving good performance.  I should have mentioned that that I have two other datetime values that I currently index and was also thinking of these when I asked the question.